# What is the percentage of dark matter in the galaxy?

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

Assuming the mass of the stars and gas within NGC 5055 is $8\times10^{10} M_{sun}$. What is the percentage of the dark matter in it?

Comment: The percentage of the punctuations in your text is exactly 0% and it is clearly visible that you dont even try to formulate a clear question this is why your question is now it the very low quality review queue I suggest to fix it ASAP

Comment: Yeah this question demonstrate very little effort and also provides very little conceptual elements.

Answer (score 2):

As a first estimate you can use the cosmological ratio of dark matter to baryonic matter which is about 5 to 1. So the mass of dark matter would be $4*10^{11} M_{\rm sun}$. This will probably be a slight over estimate as galaxies generally have a slightly lower ratios compared to the cosmological average. A more accurate estimate can be inferred from the line of sight velocities of the stars in NGC 5055.